# DJango Appengine Bforms

Tags: django, google-app-engine, bigtable

I am trying to understand how Django and Appengine work together?

1. First, question: Is this a good team?
   Experience, what is possible and what not, would be great.
2. I also read some modules like auth, admin wont work. 
   But the article is rather old, so maybe there is an update.
3. And in that tutorial one has to import bforms.

What is that?
Django Module? Appengine? Python? Bigtable?

4. How is Bigtable different from regular SQL, MySQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Regular SQL and MySQL are designed for one computer only and fail in cloud computing where you need 1,000 computers for one database. Thus the next generation databases, like bigtable, were created to distribute the data over many database servers. They are called NoSQL databases for "Not Only SQL." See http://nosql-database.org/ for a list of NoSQL databases. The google app engine apparently allows you to use the bigtable structure so you data is distributed over a dozen database servers in the cloud. So does Amazon's simple db.